# drupal image in view is displayed full screen, how to get the image smaller?

Tags: image, drupal, view, image-size

We have got a view of a content type with an image and some fields, but the image is displayed way to large. We tried to adjust maximum resolution but that just crops the image and makes it pixelated. How can we get this image to be displayed smaller?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7, you can use the core Image Styles (admin/config/media/image-styles) to set pre-defined image sizes, cropping, and more. Once you have an image style configured, you can use it to style an image in a view. This gives you complete control over image cropping and sizing. If you're using Drupal 6, the [ImageCache](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache) module does the same thing.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. The problem stays though, we adjust the image style in content type -> manage display, there we can choose between thumbnail / medium / large (or a custom made 'nodeDisplay', but the image stays large..

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to change the size in the node itself, not in a view? Have you changed the template for the content type the image is posted in at all? If you have a custom template for that page, check that you are not printing the content in a specific way (ie. other than print render($content)). Also be sure that you're editing the correct display when you go to the Manage Display section (ex Default vs. Teaser).

Comment: it was the theme, we changed the theme and now the manage display settings are applying as they should. Many thanks EJK!